# ajax request with wcf rest web service

Tags: html, ajax, web-services

I want to call web service from other website and get a response back in a html page using an Ajax call.

The data should be a response of a webservice.
I've tried a lot but I'm not getting any solution. I also crossed browser, the issue is there when calling the webservice using the ajax request.

My web service code:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        //[WebGet]
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string inputString); 
    }

It is implemented as:

    public string GetData(string inputString)
        {
            return "myData";
        }


Javascript code (From my other website):

 <script type="text/javascript">
            function click_btn() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://192.168.15.213/MyService.svc/GetData/inputString=e",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (jsonData) {
                        alert('Data: ' + jsonData);
                 `enter code here`   },
                    Error: function (e) {
                        alert('err: ' + e);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
    </script>
```

I am getting the error `404 method not allowed` when I call the webservice from another website.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, you cannot perform a request from different domains from your client context.
But what you can do is fetch the data from the external website in your own server code, and then provide it as a service for your client purposes. In fact, usually you need to give some context to data from external sources, so anyway you have to process that information before sending it to the client.

hope it helps